# Accessing a Guice singleton from Injector

Tags: java, dependency-injection, singleton, guice

I'm using Guice to create a singleton in a Java application. I used the following method in my module class:

```
@Provides
@Singleton
public LinkedBlockingQueue<String> provideLinkedBlockingQueue() {
    return new LinkedBlockingQueue<>();
  }
```

In another class I attempted to grab an instance this way:

```
public class Resource {
  private final LinkedBlockingQueue<String> bufferQueue;

  @Inject
  public Resource(LinkedBlockingQueue<String> bufferQueue) {
    this.bufferQueue = bufferQueue;
  }
```

Finally, I want to access the same instance in my application from my injector and I tried to do that this way:

```
LinkedBlockingQueue<String> bufferQueue =
        injector.getProvider(LinkedBlockingQueue.class).get();
```

Is this the correct way to go about sharing an instance between the Resource class and in my application from my injector?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is this the correct way to go about sharing an instance between the Resource class and in my application from my injector?

No, it is not.

You should use `Key<LinkedBlockingQueue<String>>` or `TypeLiteral<LinkedBlockingQueue<String>>` instead of `LinkedBlockingQueue.class`.

For instance:

```
injector.getProvider(new Key<LinkedBlockingQueue<String>>(){}).get();
```